# Image transformation in Tensorflow vs Caffe vs PIL + skimage

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, python-imaging-library, caffe, scikit-image

I created a minimum working example of an image preprocessing step which is to be ported over from Caffe v.1 to tensorflow. I am able to reproduce the steps using PIL + skimage however, I am unable to do the same in tensorflow. As observed, the L2 norm between the transformed image in Caffe and tensorflow is high which is not the case for the PIL + skimage. How do we reproduce the steps the image underwent in Caffe or PIL methods using tensorflow?

import tensorflow as tf
      import numpy as np
      from PIL import Image
      import caffe
      from skimage.transform import resize
      import requests

```
  image_url = 'https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg'
  TEST_IMAGE = 'test_image.jpg'
  DATA_LAYER = 'data_p'
  MEAN = np.array([131.26315308, 140.62084961, 142.71440125], dtype=np.float32)
  img_data = requests.get(image_url).content
  with open(TEST_IMAGE, 'wb') as handler:
      handler.write(img_data)



  def create_transformer():
    transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({DATA_LAYER: (1, 3, 224, 224)})
    transformer.set_transpose(DATA_LAYER, (2,0,1))
    transformer.set_channel_swap(DATA_LAYER,(2,1,0))
    transformer.set_mean(DATA_LAYER, MEAN)
    transformer.set_raw_scale(DATA_LAYER, 255)
    return transformer

  def transform_image_original(test_image):
    '''
    Creates a caffe.io.Transformer
    '''
    t = create_transformer()
    image_data = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(caffe.io.load_image(TEST_IMAGE) * 255))
    input_image = np.array(image_data) / 255.0
    transformed_image = t.preprocess(DATA_LAYER, input_image)
    return transformed_image

  def _resize(im, new_dims,interp_order=1):
      im_min, im_max = im.min(), im.max()
      if im_max > im_min:
          im_std = (im - im_min) / (im_max - im_min)
          resized_std = resize(im_std, new_dims, order=interp_order, mode='constant')
          resized_im = resized_std * (im_max - im_min) + im_min
      return resized_im

  def preprocess_image(TEST_IMAGE, height=224, width=224):
    '''
    replicates the caffe tranformation using PIL and skimage.transform
    '''
    with open(TEST_IMAGE, 'rb') as f:
      image = Image.open(f)
      image = image.convert('RGB')
    image = np.array(image, np.float32) / 255.0
    image = _resize(image, (224, 224))
    image = np.array(image, np.float32) * 255.0
    import scipy.misc
    scipy.misc.imsave('pil_file.jpg', image)
    image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1))
    image = image[::-1, ...] # convert RGB to BGR 
    image = image - MEAN.reshape((3, 1, 1))
    return image


  def tf_preprocess_image(TEST_IMAGE, height=224, width=224):
      '''
      preprocessing an image in tensorflow
      '''
      image_string = tf.read_file(TEST_IMAGE)
      image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3, dct_method='INTEGER_ACCURATE', 
                                   fancy_upscaling=False, acceptable_fraction=1, try_recover_truncated=True)
      image = tf.to_float(image) / 255
      image = tf.div(
                     tf.subtract(
                        image, 
                        tf.reduce_min(image)
                     ), 
                     tf.subtract(
                        tf.reduce_max(image), 
                        tf.reduce_min(image)
                     )
                     )
      if height and width:
        # Resize the image to the specified height and width.
        image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
        image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(image, [height, width],
                     align_corners=False)
        image = tf.squeeze(image, [0])
      image = tf.add(
                      tf.multiply(
                      image,
                      tf.subtract(
                          tf.reduce_max(image),
                          tf.reduce_min(image)
                          )
                      ),
                      tf.reduce_min(image)
                    )
      image = tf.to_float(image) * 255
      # RGB to BGR using strided slice
      image = image[..., ::-1]

      # Channel last to channel first
      image = tf.transpose(image, [2, 0, 1])

      # Mean subtraction
      image = tf.subtract(image, MEAN.reshape(3,1,1))
      return image

  print('Preprocessing test image using Caffe...')
  image = transform_image_original(TEST_IMAGE)

  print('Preprocessing test image using PIL + skimage.transform ...')
  image2 = preprocess_image(TEST_IMAGE)

  print('Preprocessing test image using tensorflow')
  with tf.Session() as sess:
      tf_image3 = tf_preprocess_image(TEST_IMAGE)
      image3 = tf_image3.eval()

  print('L2 norm between caffe transformation and PIL + skimage', np.linalg.norm(image - image2)) # L2 norm 
  print('L2 norm between caffe transformation and tf', np.linalg.norm(image2 - image3))
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: added the question.